# Best practice when dealing with large JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a JSON file with about 500 lines on it. I feel like dumping this JSON into the bottom of Node.JS file isn't best practice. What options are available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a separate file with the JSON contents:

filename.json:

```
{
   .. json content
}
```

Then in your JS files require it:

```
var JSON_data = require('./filename.json');

// Access the data using JSON_data.property_name
```